# Overhead of putting a thread to sleep too high?

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel, sleep, overhead

I'm working with an embedded linux system on a AM3505 processor (ARM Cortex-A8 single core). I'm trying to figure out why context switching is using more cpu time than I would expect.

While lmbench's lat_ctx benchmark tells me, a context switch should take about 40 to 50 useconds, this loop is giving me about 4.3% cpu usage according to htop.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    while(1) {
      usleep(2500);
      printf("tick\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That would result in 107.5 useconds per 'tick'.

Profiling the process with strace gives me about 8% cpu usage and:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 93.45    0.292904          29     10038           nanosleep
  6.55    0.020528           2     10039           write
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.313432                 20077           total
```

The linux kernel is configured as full preemtible realtime with hi-res timer support. Could this have any impact on the measurements? Is the cpu usage shown in htop just that inaccurate?

Answer (score 0):

There are two context switches per tick, one from executing the process to waiting for the timer and one from waiting for the timer to running the process again. So 107.5us per cycle is perfectly consistent with context switches taking around 40-50us as each cycle includes two context switches and some output.